# blazor back end model exception just shows null?

Tags: c#, windows, blazor-webassembly

Primarily I am a Desktop developer, my interest was peaked by Blazor.  After having a play with the main sample I thought I create a Blazor Client app based off it.  But I am now suddenly experiencing some strange Exception and expression debug Evaluation behaviour?

I've created a test Blazor Web Assembly application that uses VS2019 accesses a database using a simple Sql call through Dapper.  The object is created as part of the Control that renders the Page.

The page auto-refreshes by triggering a timer every 1s.  And it works fine.  Until I call the SqlConnection create method, which fails with an error because the connection string is poorly formed.

```
        public bool DoTestSql(string sqlConn, string sqlCom)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            bool bok = false;
            try
            {
                //this works
                throw new Exception("Test Exception");

                //this produces an Exception object but its very strange and is null???

                conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);

                //as a side node, going into immediate mode and typing ?sqlConn.subString(1) shows cannot be evaluated?
                //?ex.ToString() shows "unable to evaluate"
                bok = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            return bok;

        }
```

When the catch is caught (in the same function) it shows very little in the Exception object.  Printing the exception to console shows "unable to evaluate".  In fact trying to output any variable in that function does the same.

Once the connection string is correct I see "Children could not be evaluated" for the Exception?

What is going on with the Exceptions and evaluations?  Is there any way round this?

edit:  I have inserted a Sleep(10000) into the MainLayout.razor @code section to allow the debugger to spawn as per MS recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking Client Side app, means CLIENT SIDE ACCESS. Silly me for daring to dream!

You can NOT access the sql db from the app itself because its still running in the context of the web app. So CORRS /server side API applies for SQL.

[stock overflow answer similar question found later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102290/sql-connection-class-wont-connect-when-run-from-a-blazor-app)

Obvious yes, but no so obvious to a WPF guy used to full desktop access!

History: I was writing a simple Net/Sql monitoring app for a specific task I had in mind. But it needs to run locally on various PC's NOT centralized. It's at this point I thought (not engaging - can it do this brain) be a good little Blazor Client App test, see what it can do. Nope it wont. lol! Oh well back to good ol WPF then!